# ipdb commands obscured by variables

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb, ipdb

When i try to debug this sample script with ipdb:

```
n = 1
next = 1
print('end')
```

I can't execute line 3 because python variables obscure pdb commands:

```
$ ipdb test.py
> /tmp/test.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 n = 1
      2 next = 1
      3 print('end')

ipdb> next
> /tmp/test.py(2)<module>()
      1 n = 1
----> 2 next = 1
      3 print('end')

ipdb> next
> /tmp/test.py(3)<module>()
      1 n = 1
      2 next = 1
----> 3 print('end')

ipdb> next
1
ipdb> n
1
ipdb> !n
1
ipdb> !next
1
```

How can i proceed further with my code execution when both commands (n/next) aren't recognized anymore? (Let's assume s/step are also obscured by variables).

### What i tried so far:

- using ipdb3 instead of ipdb - the same problem (maybe because ipdb is link to ipdb3 in my case :))
- **using pdb - it works!** n/next commands move to next line instead of displaying python variables. What's wrong with my ipdb?
- `!!n` alleviates the problem - it runs ipdb version of `next`. If only I could `alias n !!n` and then repeatedly use `Enter` to execute it, the problem would be solved for me. But `Enter` just displays variable `n` instead of running alias `n` (which should resolve into `!!n`)

### I'm using

- Manjaro Linux 16.10
- Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
- ipdb (0.10.1)
- ipython (5.1.0)
- ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
- i don't have ~/.pdbrc file

### EDIT

The issue was fixed by by: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10050

Comment: Using `pdb3` your example works as expected. Repeated `next`  steps through the program and restarts it while `!next` shows the value of the variable. Can't reproduce in cpython's pdb.

Comment: I installed `python3-ipdb` on my linux machine and it worked there also. `next` was always treated as a command and `!next` showed the value of the variable.

Comment: I added versions of my python/ipdb/ipython to my post. Maybe it makes difference.

Comment: I am linux mint 17 x64 with python 3.4.3.

Comment: `ipdb` is the python 2 version... try `ipdb3`.... but it should still work the same way.

Comment: Snapshot of me nexting away: http://pastebin.com/FyakqK1A

Comment: ipdb3 doesn't work either, but it works with standard pdb! What's wrong with my ipdb?

Comment: Good question! Maybe somebody more closely matching your version can check. Or if ipython has its own place for questions/bug reports, maybe there.

Comment: How about adding `ipython` tag? That may get the right viewership.

Comment: `!!n` should force it to run the command instead of showing the variable. I think `!n` forces it to treat it as a variable, and `n` guesses.

Comment: @ThomasK It works! Thank you. Add it as an answer. Another question: when i add `alias n !!n` i can't just press `n` `<Enter>` `<Enter>` etc. because `<Enter>` just repeats normal `n` instead of my alias `!!n`. Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: I have created a pull request to fix the empty line problem you face. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update in 12/14/2016:**

Finally the iPython team decide to [revoke this design](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10050).

---

The solution of your problem is use `!!` statement to force standard behavior.

```
> /home/v-zit/test.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 n = 1
      2 next = 11
      3 print('end')

ipdb> n
> /home/v-zit/test.py(2)<module>()
      1 n = 1
----> 2 next = 11
      3 print('end')

ipdb> n
1
ipdb> !!n
> /home/v-zit/test.py(3)<module>()
      1 n = 1
      2 next = 11
----> 3 print('end')

ipdb> next
11
ipdb> !!next
end
--Return--
None
> /home/v-zit/test.py(3)<module>()
      1 n = 1
      2 next = 11
----> 3 print('end')

ipdb>
```

---

Reference:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9449

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10050

Comment: I don't think `del n` is a workaround - it destroys python variable that the program is using, so it will crash upon reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use brackets `(variable_name)`.

For example, if you have one vairable named `q`, you want to check it out, if you directly input `q` in the prompt, then the ipdb debugging process will break up.

```py
>>> q
```

Instead, you should input `(q)` to ckeck this vairable:

```py
>>> (q)
```